# Specify configuration file when running Tests on TFS Buid server

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, build-automation

We do not have VS Test Edition. So we are running tests by specifying the dll which contains the tests:

```
 <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\%2a.Test.dll;$(OutDir)\%2a.Tests.dll"  />
```

This works OK, except for the Integration tests that need to read information from the configuration file (App.config)

Is their a way to specify the configuration file? Or a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a RunConfigFile property to the build as follows:

```
<RunConfigFile>$(SolutionRoot)\LocalTestRun.testrunconfig</RunConfigFile>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but adding this line gives the following error: error MSB4035: The required attribute "Include" is missing from element <RunConfigFile>.

Comment: You need to put it inside a PropertyGroup, i.e.
<PropertyGroup>
    <RunConfigFile>...</RunConfigFile>
</PropertyGroup>